# Wrong query, cant figure how to handle the right output

Tags: sql

Any suggestion or correct answer, how can I view the trace code of 1-19-2 which is contains with a specific tip_part_no. Is there a method of contains?
My query is giving me wrong output.

This is my query

```
  SELECT *
    FROM pcba_info.lot_info
   WHERE trace_code = '1-19-2'
GROUP BY tip_part_no;
```

Example Data:

This is data gridview in my vb.net

```
trace_code               Tip_part_no
1-19-2                      A
1-19-2                      B
1-19-2                      A
1-19-0                      B
1-19-2                      C
1-19-2                      c
```

Output:

```
trace_code               Tip_part_no

1-19-2                      A
1-19-2                      A
```

Comment: What database platform are you using? Are you getting any errors? Show us a sample data set and what the expected result it. As is, your question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: There must be some other table(s) holding data that allows you to derive "1-19-2 A 1-19-2 A 1-19-2 A" from just "1-19-4 A". We need to know what those table(s) and columns are and the rows that are relevant to how you got to this result.

Comment: So you're saying the tip_part_no column contains no values at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably all you're looking for, but it's hard to tell without the table structure, example data, desired result, etc.

Replace xyz with the relevant tip part no

```
SELECT *
  FROM pcba_info.lot_info
 WHERE trace_code = '1-19-2'
  and tip_part_no = 'xyz';
```

Comment: This is correct but I want is, the tip_part_no as a table column in database. for example there is. trace_code. 1-19-2, 1-19-2, 1-19-2 and there is tip_part_no. A, B , C. I want to show all 1-19-2 in a specific tip_part_no in the whole list of my tip_part_no.

Comment: @user3336059 I don't understand. Can you post some example data on your table and the desired result?

Comment: It is hard to explain your answer is correct, but if I apply it to my code this will be result. cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM lot_info WHERE trace_code ='" & Trim(TextBox5.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'And tip_part_no ='" &Trim(TextBox5.Text.TrimEnd()) & "'", con)

Comment: Any suggestion to trim the column in my gridview or table column in my database not the textbox5 in my code.. Hope you can get me because your suggestion is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `LIKE` if you want to get all trace_code items containing or starting with  1-19-2. For example, on Sql Server:

```
SELECT tip_part_no, COUNT(*) as TotalTipParts
FROM pcba_info.lot_info
WHERE trace_code LIKE '1-19-2%'
GROUP BY tip_part_no
ORDER BY tip_part_no;
```

`%` is the wildcard. This will get anything starting with `1-19-2`. If you want to have the field containing that key then surround it by wildcards: `WHERE trace_code LIKE '%1-19-2%'`

Also, if you are grouping then every field other than what you are grouping by needs to be an aggregation function, such as `COUNT`, `SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX`, etc.

Answer (score -2):

if you're looking for any data containing 1-19-2, you can use wildcard in your query

this one if you're looking for data containing 1-19-2

```
SELECT * FROM pcba_info.lot_info 
WHERE trace_code like '%1-19-2%' group by tip_part_no;
```

for data starting with 1-19-2

```
SELECT * FROM pcba_info.lot_info 
WHERE trace_code like '1-19-2%' group by tip_part_no;
```

for data ends with 1-19-2

```
SELECT * FROM pcba_info.lot_info 
WHERE trace_code like '%1-19-2' group by tip_part_no;
```